# CM filter of differential input(AD7383-4)

Tags: adc, differential, common-mode

I'm trying to make a 3-phase inverter using AD7383-4 for converting analog current signal to digital.
[image: AD7383-4 applications info]

Typical application of AD7383 which is given by datasheet. AD7383 gets pseudo-differential input for an analog signal. Negative input side is practically an offset voltage constant.
Here, the question is I don't get why should we put common mode capacitor(C1). Does it work without CM capacitor?
Also the resistor of AinA+ side is located in buffer amplifier circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I don't get why should we put common mode capacitor(C1). Does it work
> without CM capacitor?*

The [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad7383-4-ad7384-4.pdf) is quite explicit about this: -

[image]

So, if you want optimal performance, you fit the recommended components.

> *Also the resistor of AinA+ side is located in buffer amplifier
> circuit.*

That is a valid concern to me and I think the circuit may be in error. I believe it makes sense to have the local feedback around that op-amp come directly from the op-amp output. Maybe take this up with AD.